# Applescript: Apply mask to an image in Pages

Tags: applescript, pdf, pages, crop

Is this possible? If yes, how?
What I want to do: I want to apply rounded corners to an image (pdf format) which I use in a pages document. 
I am searching for a way to automate this process, wether this is within Pages using a mask or outside of Pages using a script.

Thanks for any input

Comment: It may help to provide some context as to why you're wanting to automate this task? For example, are you wanting to do this to multiple images at once, or perhaps you need to do this to a large number of images? Or something else?

Comment: Yes multiple images at once using the exact same rounded corner crop box. I want to apply it to several images in a pages document. They should always look the same without me setting a manual mask inside Pages. I just want to automate this using AppleScript (one image at a time) or any other script outside of Pages.

Comment: Is there a Ghostscript that can crop pdfs with rounded corners?